# Macro to convert heights

Tags: excel, vba

I sort of already have this working, but it's not perfect. I need to convert all heights in a column to be 3 digits with no special characters. For example, these heights: `6'2" 5'10" 6'0"` would become these heights: `602 510 600`.

What is the most efficient way of doing this in a macro?

Comment: Show us the macro variations you have tried, and the problem you have run into.

Answer (score 0):

No VBA needed. You can use formulas, assuming your data is one row each.

Assuming your height is cell A1, use this formula:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=5,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'",""),"""",""),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"'",0),"""",""))
```

It's mechanics determine if there are two digits in the inches section `(Len(A1) = 5), ie -- 5'10"`). If so it just removes the `'` and the `"` with blank space. If there is only 1 digit in the inches part, it adds an extra zero.

Comment: Well, this is just a tiny part of what I want to be a pretty big macro. I want to run one macro that will run this conversion as well as many other things.

I'm kind of new to this site. I thought it would be better to split up the different functions I need to have done and then combine them. I'd like to be able to figure out this stuff myself, but would it be better/acceptable to list out everything I need done in one post?